# Which word is "which" refering to ? seat or table?

Tags: grammar

> She offered me a seat at the table, which was covered with a spotless nylon cloth.

I think it refered to "table" but I am not sure. How we can realise it?

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically it is ambiguous.  But what do you think is more likely to be covered in a cloth?  This kind of ambiguity is resolved by common sense.  It is the table which is covered by a white nylon tablecloth.